# How to add animation or effect to prettyphoto

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add image effect like slide-in / slide-out or fade-in / fade out or any random effect to my Light-box portfolio, i'm using pretty-photo plugins.

Can it be possible ?

Below is my plugin http://pastebin.com/zZMQWU9e

Answer (score 0):

you can use animation like this

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
            animation_speed: 'fast', /* fast/slow/normal */
            slideshow: 5000, /* false OR interval time in ms */
            autoplay_slideshow: false, /* true/false */
            opacity: 0.80, /* Value between 0 and 1 */
            show_title: true, /* true/false */
            allow_resize: true, /* Resize the photos bigger than viewport. true/false */
            default_width: 500,
});
```

here is the full documentation of pretyphotos which you discussed in your question.

[documentation](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation)

Comment: This is not the answer, I know these things ..I want to know how to put effects in to my source code? Like Slide in slide out..

Plz read my question once again..